# How do I set up a Gtk gpointer to a struct?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to make life easier for myself (and making a meal of it, I'm afraid) by writing some functions to help me with Gtk.  It feels like I'm close, but no cigar.

I've defined a couple of structures:

```
typedef struct action_param {
    void (*action_ptr)();
    gpointer parameter;
} action_param_type;

typedef struct document {
    GtkWindow *parent_window;
    void (*save_action_ptr)();
    void (*open_action_ptr)();
    gchar* filename;
    void* filedata;
} document_type;
```

And I've got functions which sets them up:

```
document_type build_document_with_characteristics(GtkWindow *parent_window,
                                                    void (*save_action_ptr),
                                                    void (*open_action_ptr),
                                                    gpointer filename,
                                                    gpointer filedata) {
    struct document doc;
    doc.parent_window = parent_window;
    doc.save_action_ptr = save_action_ptr;
    doc.open_action_ptr = open_action_ptr;
    doc.filename = filename;
    doc.filedata = filedata;
    return doc;
}

action_param_type set_action_with_parameter(void (*action_ptr), gpointer action_parameter) {
    action_param_type action;
    action.action_ptr = action_ptr;

    /*** these two lines for testing */
    struct document *mydata = action_parameter;
    //    g_print("%s",mydata->filename);

    action.parameter = action_parameter;
    return action;
}

GtkWidget* create_menuitem_with_parameters(void* parent_menu, char* label, struct action_param menuaction) {
    GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(label);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(parent_menu), menuitem);
    if (menuaction.action_ptr != NULL) {
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menuitem), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menuaction.action_ptr), &menuaction.parameter);
    }
    return menuitem;
}
```

Which is called as follows:

```
struct document this_document = build_document_with_characteristics(GTK_WINDOW(window),&handle_save,&handle_open,"Test Title","Test Document");
create_menuitem_with_parameters(fileMenu, "Save", set_action_with_parameter(&show_save_dialogue,&this_document));
```

My problem at the moment (and I'm sure that I'll find some more problems) is that if I uncomment the g_print line (which is there to see if I've populated everything correctly), I get:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I was wondering if the problem might be with this line:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menuitem), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menuaction.action_ptr), &menuaction.parameter);
```

I feel like I've just missed something obvious - but what is it?

Comment: If you can consider running debug build (-g) under gdb. This will give you full stack trace, and you can examine variables related to the location of the seg fault

Comment: thanks dash-o - I'm just getting started with Linux coding.  How do I do that?

Comment: First, make sure you code complied with '-g' (gcc -g ...). This can be done by adding '-g' to CFLAGS in your makefile.

Comment: Once you have a debug build, run you code with 'gdb program`, and then enter 'run arg1 arg2' (command line arguments are optional). When it stops, type 'where'. It will show you line numbers, so you know where the code breaks

Comment: It breaks on g_print("%s",mydata->filename); (unless I comment it out!). So I think that the issue is with the way that I've set up / am using the struct.

Comment: You can type 'print *mydata' to see what is the value of the structure. 'print mydata' to see the address. You might have to few 'up' to get to the right frame.

Comment: On surface, either mydata is not a valid address, or mydata->filename is not a valid address.

Comment: Have upvotes for your help.  See my answer though.  I've been a dimwit.

Comment: Instead of learning how to create functions in GTK you should learn how to create GTK costume widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling set_action_with_parameter in an earlier function with action_parameter set to NULL.  Which wasn't a problem as long as I didn't try to use it.  As soon as I g_print'd though, Seg Fault.

@pan-mroku is right as far as they go - but this fits into my over-editing too.

The solution was simple - just check if it's NULL before using it:

```
action_param set_action_with_parameter(void (*action_ptr), gpointer action_parameter) {
    action_param action;
    action.action_ptr = action_ptr;
    
    if (action_parameter != NULL) {
        action.parameter = &action_parameter;
        struct document *mydata = action_parameter;
        g_print("%s",mydata->filename);
    }
    return action;
}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer, so the question doesn't float in unanswered.

Comment: You should try to write a costume widget rather than writing a code like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a temporary pointer to the callback.

`GtkWidget* create_menuitem_with_parameters(void* parent_menu, char* label, struct action_param menuaction)` defines menuaction as passed by copy. It means that after `create_menuitem_with_parameters` returns the pointer passed in `g_signal_connect` no longer exists. You need to store the `menuaction` object somewhere and assure it is valid at the moment of running of the callback.

Comment: Not the solution in this case, but a good point.  Have an up-vote.

Comment: What the OP try there is to create a costume widget. If I am right, than definitely this is not the way to abort that.